# Proportionate the values of collection

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `double[]`and I have another `IEnumerable<double>` and another `List<double>` and also a `ObservableCollection<double>`.

All of these contain some double values.

I want to create a function which can take any of these as these collection as arguements, and that it will proportionate the values of each element in the collection so that they add to 1.

For e.g. - if array has 0.5, 1.0 and 0.5, then I can call `ProportionateIt(mycollection)`, it should modify the values to 0.25, 0.5 and 0.25 because now they sum up to 1.

So far I have tried this:

```
    private IEnumerable<double> ProportionateIt(IEnumerable<double> input)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        var newCollection = input.ToList();
        foreach (double d in newCollection)
        {
            sum+= d;
        }

        for (int i=0; i < input.Count(); i++)
        {
            newCollection[i] = newCollection[i]*(1/sum);
        }

        input = newCollection as IEnumerable<double>;
        return input;
    }
```

It has some problems

- It does not take all the types that I stated above as arguments.
- it returns a new collection, instead of modifying the original one.

Can somebody create a ProportionateIt(....) function for me?

Comment: Mzf's answer is a good solution to "proportionate" a list. You can now create overloads of the method that take different types of collections. In those methods, you put the elements in a new list and call the method which takes a list and returns a proportionated list, which in turn you put back into the original collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this

```
    private static void ProportionateIt(IList<double> input)
    {
        double sum = input.Sum(d => d);

        for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
        {
            input[i] = input[i] / sum;
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** made small changes - change `List` to `IList` as @Rawling suggest

Comment: Rather than add my own answer, I'm going to suggest that you change the parameter from `List` to `IList`, because then this will work for all of the types in the question except `IEnumerable` (which will never work anyway). Also that you drop the `()` from `Count()`.

Comment: what do you mean `passed as params` ? could you show the API ?